# How to sync head movement with Google Cardboard in Android

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I need to get head movements and according to that head turns (rotations). I need to do some work there. This is in case of inserting device in google cardboard.

I have searched the internet but I found no proper information. Please help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sensor class for this as shown below..

```
 SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                if (event.values != null && event.values.length > 1) {
                    accelDataOld = rawAccelData;
                    rawAccelData = event.values[1];

                    tweenStep = (rawAccelData - accelData) / TWEEN_TIMING;
                }
            } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                if (event.values != null && event.values.length > 1) {
                rawGyroData += event.values[0];
            }
             }
        }
    };
```